# Export to Excel - Installing Office Customization in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, excel

I am exporting to excel file in MVC4 application.
 **Excel**

```
public class ExporttoExcel : ActionResult
{
public GridView ExcelGridView { get; set; }
public string fileName { get; set; }
public int totalQuantity;
public decimal totalPrice1;
public string x1;

public ExporttoExcel(GridView gv, string pFileName, int totalQty, decimal totalPrice, string x)
{
  x1= x;
  ExcelGridView = gv;
  fileName = pFileName;
  totalQuantity = totalQty;
  totalPrice1 = totalPrice;
}
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
    HttpContext curContext = HttpContext.Current;
    curContext.Response.Clear();
    curContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    curContext.Response.Charset = "";
    curContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    curContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";      
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    if (x1== "111")
    {
      htw.WriteLine("<html><head>");
      //code logic
      ExcelGridView.HeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
      ExcelGridView.RenderControl(htw);
      htw.WriteLine("</body></html>");
    }
    else
    {
      htw.WriteLine("Data");
      ExcelGridView.RenderControl(htw);
    }
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
    MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.ASCII);
    curContext.Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
    curContext.Response.End();
    }
}
```

The below error occurs and the excel file is not opened.

```
Error : 
From: file:///d:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestExcelAddIn.vsto did not succeed.
```

Any mistake in my code. What should I do to resolve this error. ?
**EDIT :** 
This error occurs only in IE. Firefox and Chrome opens the excel file.

Comment: Excel is designed to open Excel files. What you have done here is an HTML file.

Comment: Why don't you send the content directly to the Response?  Do you need the intermediate file?  And which branch of the `if` is executing?

Comment: @Darin yes. i am passing a gridview.It is the main thing which has to be exported to excel..the html is only for decorating the excel.

Comment: Yeah but Excel doesn't understand HTML. In Excel 2007 or later you could use the [`Open XML SDK`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) to build a real Excel file.

Comment: @Darin - Excel does understand HTML tables.  It's a common method for sending an Excel file to the client: you just set an Excel mime type and send the data as an HTML table.  You can even add some styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the three files in my local machine in the location where the error was specified.

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestExcelAddIn.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestExcelAddIn.dll.manifest
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestExcelAddIn
```

It works fine and IE opens the Excel file.